# Run-Time error '1004': application-defined or object - defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy over a few cells and move other cells down. Not sure what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated. My worksheet pages names are: Rules, Trade_Inputs, Portfolio, Trade_History.

````
Worksheets("Trade_History").Range("journal1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Worksheets("Trade_History").Range("a2").Value = Worksheets("Trade_Inputs").Range("E6").Value
Worksheets("Trade_History").Range("a1:N19").Value = Worksheets("Trade_Inputs").Range("Journal").Value
Call GoToTradeHistory
End Sub```
````

Comment: What is `"Journal1"`?

Comment: Do you have a named range called "journal1"? Or are you trying to use that as a variable?

Comment: It's a name range